# Can I post to a Shared Data Extension, and trigger an email from a child business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, cloudpage, parent

My client has several brands, and we're putting all our eggs into a single basket (that is, a shared DE at the Parent MID)

With the Shared Data Extension at the Parent level, we run Queries to update each individual child BU mailing Data Extension.  We'd like to create a sign-up page for each Child Business Unit that writes to the Shared Parent Data Extension and then triggers a Welcome for that brand.

While I can trigger from the Parent MID, the FROM address and subdomains are for the Parent, and not the child BU.  That said, is it possible to trigger a Welcome or a Journey when the subscribe happens?  I know I can schedule an Automation to move the data and start the trigger, but I'd like it to be triggered.

Help!

Comment: Is they shared DE a sendable one?

Comment: Yes, absolutely it is

Comment: Ok great! Then I guess you can use this DE as entry event of the Journey and use decision activity to send emails according the brand. Does that help ?

Comment: I tried that, but I can't seem to trigger the email from the child BU.  This is where I'm stuck.  

The parent BU has a different subdomain and branding -- each child BU has the appropriate branding elements.  This is what I'm trying to figure out. 

Is there a way to start a journey to move the members to the child BUs (based on data within their user profile) and then trigger a welcome?

Comment: Where is your journey? In child BU or Parent?

Comment: I can build it wherever... just thinking aloud as to how I can build this

Comment: If you build in the child BU and use shared DE as entry.. I honk you should be able to send the email

Comment: That might work- can I trigger the automation from a new join in the shared DE ... my other idea is have the sign-up forms write to the Child BUs, trigger the welcome automation, and then write the data into the shared DE at the parent level?

Thank you Maneesh!

Comment: Np! I did think about writing straight to child BU but thought that it would be a fundamental design change :)   ..

Comment: Adding users to a child DE, triggering the email and then completing an "Update Contact" into the Parent Shared DE isn't working... Only the EMAIL ADDRESS is updating into the Shared DE, and not all of the other fields in the Data Extension.

There must be a use-case like mine built into the platform.  It seems too common not to exist!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use UPSERT DE AMPscript, as this accomplishes exactly what I need in my use-case.  That is, deploying from the CHILD and then updating the data in the ENT.DE